# Derive/generate an Arbitrary[T] for a simple Java value class

Tags: scala, shapeless, scalacheck

I have a Java class `MyClass` and I want to create an `Arbitrary[MyClass]` in Scalacheck. An implementation of `Arbitrary` for `MyClass` will just call `arbitrary[T]` for each of the constructor arguments and then do `new MyClass` with all the args:

```
Arbitrary {
  for {
    a <- arbitrary[A]
    b <- arbitrary[B]
    c <- arbitrary[C]
  } yield new MyClass(a, b, c)
}
```

The constructor takes many fields and I expect to have to do this for other classes in the future. How can I avoid a giant for comprehension? Is there a way to derive an `Arbitrary[MyClass]`?

It looks like the Shapeless library can derive these type classes for Scala case classes but as far as I can tell it doesn't work for Java classes.

Comment: If you define your own `shapeless.Generic` instances for your Java classes, [shapeless-scalacheck](https://github.com/alexarchambault/scalacheck-shapeless) can derive the `Arbitrary` instances for you. This doesn't necessarily help you in terms of boilerplate line count, though.